# How can I connect sharing button for social networks using react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, social-networking

I have a isomorphic app written by React, Redux, React-Router. It needs connect sharing buttons for social networks, such as VK,TW,OK,FB.I have no idea how do it.
I would be grateful for the help.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some additional information?

Comment: there are actually multiple third-party solutions to accomplish this:
https://github.com/olahol/react-social
https://github.com/mxstbr/sharing
https://github.com/nygardk/react-share